# How to keep in data frame every ID once preferring largest value fist in case of tie newest in case of tie random

Tags: r, random

I got a large DF with about 250K obs. and 19 variables about peoples graduation data. People are in the DF multiple times. I need to make two new DF where every person appears only once (ID) per DF. My true DF has more columns but for the example i took out 3 that are needed and 2 as an example of other background information in my DF.

ID - a persons unique ID

Level - Shows the level of education.  Higher the number the better: Example 8 = Phd, 7 = Masters

Year - The year of the graduation

Field - background information on the field of study. We need to keep this data.

Gender - Gender of the person. We need to keep this data.

```
 Orignal DF named "Graduations"
ID    Level     Year     Field     Gender
1       4       2016      31         M
1       5       2016      43         M
2       6       2010      12         F
2       7       2012      12         F
2       8       2017      19         F
3       5       2011      12         F
3       5       2009      31         F
4       6       2018      43         M
4       6       2018      44         M
5       5       2015      19         M
5       6       2011      32         M
```

DF 1 is named "Highest" meaning highest level of graduation. In this DF we only keep rows where the person has reached their highest level of education. If a person has reached it more then once then we keep the row with the highest and newest graduation and if both are a tie then we choose one randomly.

```
 "Highest"
ID    Level     Year     Field     Gender
1       5       2016      43         M   (Row kept because it was the highest level)
2       8       2017      19         F   (Row kept because it was the highest level)
3       5       2011      12         F   (Row kept because it was the highest level and newest)
4       6       2018      43         M   (Row chosen randomly)
5       6       2011      32         M   (Row Kept because it was the Highest level)
```

DF 2 is named "Last" meaning the last obtained level of graduation. In this DF we only keep row with the newest data. If a person has had more then one graduation per year then we choose the highest level if that is also a tie then at random (Does not need to be the same random row as was in DF1)

```
 "Last"
ID    Level     Year     Field     Gender
1       5       2016      43         M     (Row kept because it was the newest and highest level)
2       8       2017      19         F     (Row kept because it was the newest)
3       5       2011      12         F     (Row kept because it was the newest)
4       6       2018      44         M     (Row chosen randomly)
5       5       2015      19         M     (Row Kept because it was the newest)
```

I tried to search for it on the stackoverflow but did not find what i was looking for. I might have used wrong keywords.

I prefer base R functions but if needed the most common packages are also ok. This is because this DF is on a secure computer and installing uncommon packages takes forever as i must make a request for it. Most common ones are already installed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` soolution

It's not quite elegent but it works.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('ID    Level     Year     Field     Gender
1       4       2016      31         M
1       5       2016      43         M
2       6       2010      12         F
2       7       2012      12         F
2       8       2017      19         F
3       5       2011      12         F
3       5       2009      31         F
4       6       2018      43         M
4       6       2018      44         M
5       5       2015      19         M
5       6       2011      32         M')

df1 <- dt[,head(.SD[Level==max(Level)],1),by = .(ID)]

df2 <- dt[,highest_lvl_year:=max(Level),.(ID,Year)][,
            flag:=fifelse(Year==max(Year),fifelse(Level==highest_lvl_year,"Y","N"),"N"),by=.(ID)][,
            head(.SD[flag=="Y"],1),by=.(ID)]
df1
#>    ID Level Year Field Gender
#> 1:  1     5 2016    43      M
#> 2:  2     8 2017    19      F
#> 3:  3     5 2011    12      F
#> 4:  4     6 2018    43      M
#> 5:  5     6 2011    32      M
df2[,1:5]
#>    ID Level Year Field Gender
#> 1:  1     5 2016    43      M
#> 2:  2     8 2017    19      F
#> 3:  3     5 2011    12      F
#> 4:  4     6 2018    43      M
#> 5:  5     5 2015    19      M
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If i put in the first code i get the following error: Error in head(.SD["Level" == max(Level)], 1) : object 'Level' not found. When i change Level,s to "Level" then it runs but the df1 has 0 variables on it. When i run the second code i get error: Error in `:=`(highest_lvl_year, max(Level)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":="). The code is to complex for me to understand what i did wrong.

Comment: Can you try `setDT(your dataset)` before all this code and make sure your columns names are aligned with the codes